# Insane reaction time

Tags: super-powers

I have a protagonist in my story who is a superman. He acquired a reaction time of a couple nanoseconds.
While walking along a beach, an assassin shot at him, from behind, with a Steyr IWS 2000 rifle [Visiting the Steyr Arms HQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVQR8FOTBy0); [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steyr_IWS_2000).

Since his reflexes are so fast, would he be able to detect the pressure wave of the 5.56mm dart travelling at 1,450 meters per second, and dodge it? Would the pressure wave even be in front of the projectile?

EDIT: He's invulnerable, the dart would pinch, not penetrate, his skin to a depth of about a centimeter, and destroy or glance off.

EDIT2: His reaction time (from human norm to nanosecond) can be altered at will.

Comment: The speed of sound in air is about 340 meters per second. The speed of sound in a material is the speed at which pressure waves propagate through the material. The air in front of the projectile has no way of knowing that something is coming 4.2 times faster than sound.

Comment: he must find the world incredibly boring, I bet he secretly craves death. imagine watching avengers endgame but it takes 9000 hours to watch once.

Comment: He only employs that reaction time when needed. Otherwise, he experiences the world as we do. He didn't think much of that flick. :)

Comment: To add to the answers... quality reflexes have nothing to do with detecting the minuscule pressure wave caused by a bullet/dart. Unless your protagonist also has super sensitive skin (meaning when the significant other blows in the protag's ear, it's incredibly painful) to feel that pressure wave with a short enough nerve-to-brain transmittal time that there's still time for any reflexes at all to save the day.

Comment: I would need super sensitive skin to feel a poke in my back? Then why would he?

Comment: @catsteevens Am I missing something here? The super's invulnerable, so dodging the bullet is irrelevant - but you asked. The reaction time depends on the ability to detect the incoming bullet, and you said that detection was manifest by sensing the pressure wave in front of an object that's designed to minimize that wave. Factually, if you want your super to dodge the bullet, then yes, my friend, the super must feel the air early enough for any reaction time to work.... and that means super-sensitive skin that would make a gentle breeze feel incredibly painful. This Q doesn't make sense.

Comment: What aspects of real world physics apply in your world?  The comments include an increasingly large array of super abilities which conflict with real world physics.  Sandersons first law of magic may be a more important law, rather than Newton's or Einstein's.

Comment: @John You're thinking of Wakanda Forever, the first movie with its running time as part of the title.

Comment: Note that light only travels about a foot in one nanosecond. In general, even the image of his surroundings his eyes see is delayed by so much that such a reflex speed is meaningless. Even for touch, the neural signals involved in him sensing pressure and responding reflexively to it follow such a convoluted path that they would have to be traveling faster than light to allow such a reflex speed. Superhero physics is involved, so this isn't necessarily a problem, but it'd actually not violate physics any more and might have a more believable mechanism if he reacted just *before* the stimulus.

Comment: True. At his top speed of 99,000+ miles per second, and in his nanosecond mode; as he perceives it, he can only move about 10 inches per second. If he reacted before, what would trigger his reaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "advantage" your superman will have is that he gets to feel the projectile's arrival and any subsequent damage in much finer detail than a normal human would.  Consider the difference in the video viewing experience between normal film speed and the 10k frames per second produced by a super slow-motion camera.  It won't hurt him any more than a 1cm penetration and impact percussion would hurt any of us, but he'll get to feel it in more detail and for a subjectively much longer span of time.

Answer (score 14):

## No

Credit to @AlexP who answered this in a comment.

The projectile is moving faster than sound, and therefore is moving faster than a pressure wave propagates through air.  The first sign your superhuman would have that the bullet was en route was when it penetrated their skin.

Additionally, reflexes are kind of immaterial without knowing how quickly they can move their body entirely.  I can certainly react at reflex speed to a cyclist bearing down on me, and my reflexes are much faster than the speed of a bike.  That doesn't mean I can get out of the way.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151525/discussion-on-answer-by-jdunlop-insane-reaction-time); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The speed of sound in water is 1500 meters/sec, so if the sound of the rifle travels into the water and overtakes him, and he could percieve the sound as a slight pressure wave, he could deduce that something exploded behind him. If he can turnaround move fast enough, he could escape the attack.